# How do I make a variable to count the number of tiles through the program

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am basically making this java program about a tile game for the user to interact with. This is one of the 6 classes and I need a variable to keep track of the tiles. How do I do that?

```java
/*
 * Activity 8.2 Tester File
 */
public class TileTester {
    private static String[] tileValues = {
            "lion", "lion",
            "penguin", "penguin",
            "dolphin", "dolphin",
            "fox", "fox",
            "monkey", "monkey",
            "turtle", "turtle"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*2d array*/
        String[][] gameBoard = {{"lion", "lion", "penguin", "penguin"},
                {"dolphin", "dolphin", "fox", "fox"},
                {"monkey", "monkey", "turtle", "turtle"}};
        /*nested for loop*/
        for (int row = 0; row < gameBoard.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < gameBoard[0].length; column++) {
                System.out.println(gameBoard[row][column]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "keep track of tiles?" To what end? Maybe if you actually described the game you were trying to make, your question would be easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your question fully, but in second loop you should use:

**gameBoard[row].length;**

```
for(int column = 0; column < gameBoard[row].length; column++) {
    System.out.println(gameBoard[row][column]);  
}
```